# Where do we see the months corresponding to the Shvatim?

Tags: calendar, months

I saw in Pri Tzaddik of R' Tzadok that it's written in sefer of the Arizal that the months are keneged (corresponding) to the Shvatim (tribes), according to how they were encamped in the Midbar (Desert/Wilderness). For example, Nissan is Yehuda. And he was bringing down how Kislev is Binyamin. 
Does anyone know where this is written in the sifrei Arizal, or maybe even earlier sources?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you remember where this was in pri tzaddik?

Comment: I think the section was Hakdama lechanuka, or rosh chodesh chanuka.

Comment: Bnei Yissaschar at the beginning of each month tells you who it corresponds to. I believe he tells you from which sefer of Arizal he is quoting, or at least newer versions cite it, but I don't have a copy on me.

Comment: You're likely looking for a passage in Kabbalstic or Hassidic lit., but FWIW the Tanchuma (Buber, vol. 1 [Vayeshev, pg. 181](https://books.google.com/books?id=NcYtAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA3&ots=Zbr9qmHiIg&dq=%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9F&pg=RA4-PA181#v=onepage&q&f=false)) has a tradition that God created his world in rubrics of twelve - the tribes and the months being two of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a kabbalistic idea is discussed by [R. Josef Gikatilla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Abraham_Gikatilla) in his Shaare Orah ([Gate 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20243&st=&pgnum=135)).

An English trans. of the above is found in 'Gates of Light' (232ff.) by Avi Weinstein.